# Satisfaction of Bessel equation by any other function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, bessel-functions

Is it possible that any function $y(x)$ other than Bessel group of functions, satisfy Bessel's equation?

$$x^2 \dfrac{d^2 y}{d x^2} + x \dfrac{d y}{d x} + (1-n^2/x^2) y = 0.$$

Comment: Yes, it's possible. With equivalent function, such as StruveH. Or with more general functions : Hypergeometric0F1, hypergeometric1F1, MeijierG, ... for example.

Comment: Sphereical Bessel functions which reduce to trig functions...

Answer (score -1):

[Neumann functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NeumannFunction.html) are what you'd be interested in. They form a set of solutions to the Bessel equation that have a singular point at the origin.

Comment: Neumann functions are still Bessel functions

Comment: I would disagree.